# Checking datareader to be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I check if my datareader is completely empty ?

Not talking about nullvalues but completely empty (no records).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.hasrows.aspx) property to check if there are any rows or not.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Well, you don't really need it, but it can simplify the logic sometimes if you can check for rows before starting to call `Read`.

Comment: What I meant is that I have seen some sample-code (from MS) that does `if (HasRows) { while (Read()) ... }`. Never knew if there was a point to that.